# Error al destruir ventana y ejecutar una nueva en Customtkinter

Tags: python

Tengo 2 clases, dichas clases son 2 ventanas diferentes.
Al momento de presionar un botón el cual destruye la ventana principal y ejecuta la secundaria me arroja un error el cual adjunto a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La función que ejecuta el botón es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debido a ese error no puedo crear el ejecutable de manera correcta.

El código de la clase principal es el siguiente:

```html
import customtkinter
from clase import *


class ejecutable:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.window.geometry('600x400')
        self.window.title('Prueba')

        topFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.window, fg_color='dark gray')
        topFrame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)


        b = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=topFrame, command=self.listenerButton)
        b.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)


        self.window.mainloop()


    def listenerButton(self):
        self.window.destroy()
        c = clase()



e = ejecutable()
```

La clase secundaria, la cual es ejecutada por el botón para realizar la creación de la siguiente ventana es la siguiente:

```html
import customtkinter


class clase:
    def __init__(self):
        window = customtkinter.CTk()
        window.geometry('600x400')
        window.title('Prueba')

        topFrame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=window, fg_color='red')
        topFrame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)


        window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Pon el código y los mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. Además, al ser código Python, no deberías colocarlo en un snippet, ya que además de que no es posible ejecutarlo en la pregunta (para eso están los snippets), solo funcionan para HTML+CSS+JS. Dale el formato adecuando agregando ``` una línea antes y una después de tu código. Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Investigando y realizando pruebas es un error común que no interfiere con el trabajo, simplemente se ignora dicho error.